# Kivy expand and collapse a panel to hide the inside itens

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to kivy and I am trying do create a widget to colapse and expand after click in a button. When it is colapsed the inside widgets must be hidden, and when it is extended the height should be minimum heigh possible.
I did this implementation, but when expanded i couldn't set the height properly, and the childrens don't hide when colapse...
I know that already there is a widget that do this in kivyMD library, but I need create a differente layout for the button and the childrens, so if someone could help me...

kivy file: teeeste.kv

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<CLabel@Label>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 40

<CButton@Button>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: C("#455A64") if self.state == "normal" else (0.26,0.26,0.26,0.85)
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: 10,10,10,10
    size_hint: None,None
    size: 300,40

<Box@GridLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: 10,10,10,10
    cols: 1
    size_hint: None,None
    width: 300
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "tb-lr"


FloatLayout:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "top"
        padding: 0,30,0,0
        Box:
            id: box
            CButton:
                text: "Press to expand or colapse"
                on_release: box.height = 300 if box.height == 40 else 40
            CLabel:
                text: "abc"
            CLabel:
                text: "abc"
            CLabel:
                text: "abc"
            CLabel:
                text: "abc"
```

python file:

```
# coding: utf-8

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex


Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex("#424242")


class TesteApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return aplicativo


aplicativo = Builder.load_file("teeeste.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TesteApp().run()
```

I did the changes suggested by @JohnAnderson and I tried implement other Box inside each other, but sometimes after click on "NUMBER 3" button the childrens inside the related box stop of expand.
Here is the actual code:

kivy: teeeste.ky

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<CLabel@Label>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 40

<CButton>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: C("#455A64") if self.state == "normal" else (0.26,0.26,0.26,0.85)
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: 10,10,10,10
    size_hint: 1.0,None
    height: 40

<Box@GridLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    size_hint: 0.8,None
    height: self.minimum_height

FloatLayout:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "top"
        padding: 0,30,0,0
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            size_hint: None, 0.9
            width: 300
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                spacing: 5
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                Box:
                    id: box
                    cols: 1
                    CButton:
                        text: "NUMBER 1"
                        on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box)
                    CLabel:
                        text: "aaa"
                Box:
                    id: box2
                    cols: 1
                    CButton:
                        text: "NUMBER 2"
                        on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box2)
                    CLabel:
                        text: "bbb"
                Box:
                    id: box3
                    cols: 1
                    CButton:
                        text: "NUMBER 03"
                        on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box3)
                    Box:
                        id: box4
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 1"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box4)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "111"
                    Box:
                        id: box5
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 2"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box5)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "222"
                    Box:
                        id: box6
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 3"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box6)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "333"
                    Box:
                        id: box7
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 4"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box7)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "444"
                    Box:
                        id: box8
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 5"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box8)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "555"
                    Box:
                        id: box9
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 6"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box9)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "666"
                    Box:
                        id: box10
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 7"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box10)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "777"
                    Box:
                        id: box11
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 8"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box11)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "888"
                    Box:
                        id: box12
                        cols: 1
                        CButton:
                            text: "CHILD 9"
                            on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box12)
                        CLabel:
                            text: "999"
```

Python file: main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.11.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class CButton(Button):
    def exp_or_collapse(self, id):
        if id.height == self.height:
            # expand:
            for child in id.children:
                child.height = 40
                child.opacity = 1
        else:
            # collapse
            for child in id.children:
                if child != self:
                    child.height = 0
                    child.opacity = 0


class expApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("exp.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    expApp().run()
```

[Imagage of the all box colapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfRwa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to write a method to do it in the `CButton` class:

```
class CButton(Button):
    def exp_or_collapse(self, box):
        if box.height == self.height:
            # expand
            for child in box.children:
                child.height = 40
                child.opacity = 1
        else:
            # collapse
            for child in box.children:
                if child != self:
                    child.height = 0
                    child.opacity = 0
```

Then use that in the `kv` file:

```
FloatLayout:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "top"
        padding: 0,30,0,0
        Box:
            id: box
            CButton:
                text: "Press to expand or colapse"
                on_release: self.exp_or_collapse(box)
            CLabel:
                text: "abc"
            CLabel:
                text: "abc"
            CLabel:
                text: "abc"
            CLabel:
                text: "abc"
```

The opacity fiddling is required to completely hide the `CLabels`, since a `Label` will display its `text` even if its size is 0.

The above code is designed to handle only `CLabels` and `CButtons` in a `Box`. To expand it to handle general children of the `Box`, the `exp_or_collapse()` can be modified as:

```
class CButton(Button):
    removedChildren = ListProperty([])

    def exp_or_collapse(self, id):
        if len(self.removedChildren) > 0:
            # expand:
            # re-add all children
            self.removedChildren.reverse()
            for child in self.removedChildren:
                id.add_widget(child)
            self.removedChildren = []
        else:
            # collapse
            # remove all children (except ourself)
            for child in id.children:
                if child != self:
                    self.removedChildren.append(child)
            for child in self.removedChildren:
                id.remove_widget(child)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works very well. I will try implement more CButtons inside the Box, and see if it will works as I need. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I updated the code with your tips, but when I put other "Box" with a Button inside, after click sometimes the child buttons don't work properly. I edited my question explaining better, with the code.

Comment: The code that I posted in my answer was designed for the question that you posted. I have modified my answer to include a more general solution.